# 0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream in PHP quickbooks

Tags: php, quickbooks

Where am i going wrong ?

```
function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, 
    $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
// Grab the data from our MySQL database
//$arr = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM q_firms WHERE id = '$firm_id'"));

$query = "SELECT 
                        DISTINCT (q_firms.firm_id), q_firms.firm, q_firms.status,
                        q_offices.address1, q_offices.address2, q_offices.city, q_offices.state, q_offices.zip, q_offices.country, q_offices.phone as office_phone, q_offices.fax as office_fax,
                        q_users.first, q_users.middle, q_users.last, q_users.title, q_users.email, q_users.phone, q_users.fax
                    FROM 
                        (q_firms)
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        q_offices ON q_offices.office_id=q_firms.main_office
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        q_users ON q_users.firm_id=q_firms.firm_id AND q_users.b_contact='Y'
                    WHERE q_firms.firm_id='$firm_id'";

            $query1 = mysql_query($query);

 $arr = mysql_fetch_array($query1);



$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $arr['firm_id']. '">
                <CustomerAdd>
                    <Name>' . $arr['firm'] . '</Name>
                    <CompanyName>' . $arr['firm'] . '</CompanyName>
                    <FirstName>' . $arr['first'] . '</FirstName>
                    <LastName>' . $arr['last'] . '</LastName>
                    <BillAddress>
                        <Addr1>' . $arr['address1'] . '</Addr1>
                        <Addr2>' . $arr['address2'] . '</Addr2>
                        <City>' . $arr['city'] . '</City>
                        <State>' . $arr['state'] . '</State>
                        <PostalCode>' . $arr['zip'] . '</PostalCode>
                        <Country>' . $arr['country'] . '</Country>
                    </BillAddress>
                </CustomerAdd>
            </CustomerAddRq>
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>';



return $xml;
}
```

Comment: Did you search first? This question has been answered many, many times on StackOverflow already. Please tell us what you're tried already, and post the actual XML you're sending to QuickBooks (find it in the quickbooks_log table).

Comment: Yeah, Thanks Keith, i could resolve the issue. appreciate your help.